# What is the expectation of $ X^2$ where $ X$ is distributed normally?

Tags: statistics, normal-distribution

I know that if $X$ were distributed as a standard normal, then $X^2$ would be distributed as [chi-squared](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chi-squared_distribution), and hence have expectation $1$, but I'm not sure about for a general normal.

Thanks

Comment: if  $ Y \sim \mathcal{N}(\mu,\sigma^2)$ then you have $ Y = \sigma X +\mu $ where $ X \sim \mathcal{N}(0,1)$

Answer (score 50, accepted):

Use the identity
$$
E(X^2)=\text{Var}(X)+[E(X)]^2
$$
and you're done.

Since you know that $X\sim N(\mu,\sigma)$, you know the mean and variance of $X$ already, so you know all terms on RHS.